# File not moved to specific folder after uploading - PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I am using php 5.3 on client machine. while xammp is installed on the server of practical lab of our college.
I wanted to upload a file and then want to move it in specific folder.
So code of uploading file is working properly and uploaded successfully on our server. 
But now i want to move that file in the folder(where i careated php project and form) which i created on my client pc.
How can i do it?
Here is the code which i tried but it just upload file to server but cannot move.

Here is php code

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))

{

    $fname=$_FILES['file']['name'];
    if($_FILES['file']['name']!="")
    {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"/images".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        echo "uploaded";

    }
    else
    {
        echo "Not Uploaded";
    }
}


?>
```

HTML code

```
 <form  method="post" name="frm1" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label for="fileSelect">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
 </form>
```

After selecting and submitting the file it shows the output 
"uploaded".
But does not display in the images folder which i created in the project.

Comment: is the `images` directory at root level?

Comment: @RamRaider I created directory like D:\Sem-2\PHP\Unit-3\file-upload\images

Comment: "_But now i want to move that file in the folder(where i careated php project and form) which i created on my client pc_" `move_uploaded_file` is used to move the file on the server, not the client. You'd need to download the file

Comment: `"Not Uploaded";`? Maybe you want to `echo "Not Uploaded";`?

Comment: OK - which is the DOCUMENT_ROOT in the above path? The fact that the path begins with drive D suggests that possibly this is outside of the document root altogether ( unless you are running your webserver from the D drive? )

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"/images/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Maybe you have missed "/" between dir and name.

Reference link : http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that the target directory is not within the root structure for your site so the `root relative path` you have assigned `/images` is not available. If that is the case use a full path string to that directory as below:

```
<?php

    /* utility to recursively create folder path if needed */
    function createpath( $path=NULL, $perm=0644 ) {
        if( !file_exists( $path ) ) {
            createpath( dirname( $path ) );
            mkdir( $path, $perm, TRUE );
            clearstatcache();
        }
    }

    if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) && !empty( $_FILES['file'] ) ) {

        $status = false;
        $writeenable=true;

        $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $error = $_FILES['file']['error'];
        $tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];



        /* If the directory is in the DOCUMENT_ROOT structure */
        /*
        $targetdir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/images';
        if( !file_exists( $targetdir ) )createpath( $targetdir );
        */

        /* If the directory is outside of the DOCUMENT_ROOT */
        $targetdir = 'D:\Sem-2\PHP\Unit-3\file-upload\images';

        if( !file_exists( $targetdir ) ) exit('Warning: Target directory cannot be found');
        if( !is_writable( $targetdir ) ) {
            if( $writeenable ) chmod( $targetdir,0644 );
            else exit('unable to write to target directory');
        }

        if( $error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK && is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) ){
            $status = move_uploaded_file( $tmp , $targetdir . '/' . $name );
        }

        echo $status ? 'uploaded' : 'Not Uploaded';
    }
?>
```

Comment: try `chmod( $targetdir, 0644 );`

Comment: Warning: chmod(): No such file or directory in D:\PHP\file-upload\frmFileUp.php on line 48
unable to write to target directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];  //Temporary file location


$fileDestination ='./uploadScript';  // put a **dot** '.' before the **slash** '/'


move_uploaded_file ($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);  // move file FROM '$fileTmpName' TO '$fileDestination'
```

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php